# Convert file format from system

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am working on an application where we store candidate resumes .So,i need to convert those files sent by an individual into .doc format from my application it self.
I am using angular js , node js and mongo db to develop my system

Could any one suggest me how i can achieve this scenario using node js

Comment: Try out this module https://github.com/Ziv-Barber/officegen I have't used it so it's a google guess. But it looks like it's what you're searching for.

Answer (score 1):

officegen makes sense as a staring point, as suggested. if that does not work, you could dig into the office api. http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office